# HTACCESS multiple subfolders- best practice?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is the code I use to get three virtual subfolders with .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?url=$1&sub=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?url=$1&sub=$2&subsub=$3 [L]
```

the question is: is it possible to make it simpler? For example:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?url=$1&sub=$2&subsub=$3 [L]
```

I know this won't work. I am just trying to figure out if it is the only way to add more subfolders. What if I need, let's say, six (url/sub/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5....etc)??

Thank you in advance

Comment: You would be much better off catching everything and sending it to `url`. Then use `explode` to split the segments.

Comment: yes, Mike, I know that. The question is htaccess related though. Thank you anyway!

Comment: My comment is htaccess and PHP related. You need both. There is no way for Apache to automatically split each segment to a query string parameter, which is why you need to catch everything and let PHP do the grunt-work.

Comment: Mike, I didn't say anything about automatic splitting. I asked if there was a way to make the mentioned above HTACCESS statement shorter (instead of three or, let's say, five columns - only one).

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that it can't be done. *There is no way for Apache to automatically split each segment to a query string parameter...*